# Virtual Android Apk Crash

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual

I realised that most apps, especially games, force shut on virtual android and other virtual emulator like VMOS and F1VM lite. I downloaded Free fire on most of this platforms and no platform could run the game; The game will undoubtedly start but after 40secs into the game it will crash. I think the problem stems from the game but I have my doubts because it used to run before. This is why I am trying to delve deep into the understanding of this framework.
And, Yes, I have already activated the virtual emulator via wireless debugging and I am very sure it is not a memory allocation issue. I use android 13 and most these virtual OS ask for activation which I definitely comply with. I will greatly appreciate if anyone can lecture me.

I tried to activate it and even run the 32 bit version of VMOS but it still ceased to run

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.